# TSQL - excluding the rows that matches with temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a help with SQL SELECT query.

I have `[Details]` sql table below.  I want to select rows that have matching group id and that does not exist in given temp table

```
DetailID   GroupID     TemplateID   DocumentID
------------------------------------------------------
1            A            2             NULL
2            A            NULL          33
3            A            10            NULL *

4            B            NULL          33
5            B            4             NULL *

6            C            2             NULL
7            C            4             NULL *
8            C            NULL          55   *
```

@tmpDetails - A Templarary table that has TemplateID and DocumentID

```
TemplateID  DocumentID  
---------------------------
2           NULL
NULL        33
```

I want to select rows that are in group A, B and C and does not have matching TemplateID and DocumentID from @tmpDetail table

so the select query should return the rows with detail ID 3,5,7,8

The query below does not return anything

```
SELECT * from Details D
WHERE D.GroupID IN ('A','B','C') AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT d2.DetailID FROM Details d2 
 JOIN @tmpDetails t ON  d2.TemplateID IS NOT NULL 
       AND d2.TemplateID = t.TemplateID 
       OR d2.DocumentID IS NOT NULL AND d2.DocumentID = t.DocumentID)
```

whatever the condition have in JOIN it should be the where condition but i am sure how do compose that SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not connect your nested query with the main table (`D`).

You can get rid of the join and do this:

```
SELECT * FROM Details D 
WHERE D.GroupID IN ('A','B','C') AND NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 FROM @tmpDetails t 
    WHERE  (D.TemplateID IS NOT NULL AND D.TemplateID = t.TemplateID) OR 
           (D.DocumentID IS NOT NULL AND D.DocumentID = t.DocumentID))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT D.*
FROM
    Details D
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 1 Match
        FROM @tmpDetails T
        WHERE
            D.TemplateID = T.TemplateID
            OR D.DocumentID = T.DocumentID
    ) T
WHERE
    D.GroupID IN ('A','B','C')
    AND T.Match IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NOT EXISTS` and subquery with `INTERSECT` to handle `NULL` values:

```
SELECT * FROM Details D
WHERE D.GroupID IN ('A', 'B', 'C') 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TemplateID, DocumentID FROM @tmpDetails INTERSECT 
                  SELECT D.TemplateID, D.DocumentID)
```