# mySQL Join Tables but exclude ALL rows with a certain ID/value based on matching criteria from another column (criteria contained in only some rows)

Tags: mysql

Very new to SQL so I don't even know how to phrase my question properly, and maybe that's why I can't seem to find an answer.
What I am trying to do essentially is include or exclude all rows from a table by an ID column based on matching criteria from another column. Instead what happens is only the rows with the criteria are included/excluded rather than all with the matching ID.

I think I am trying to essentially do what is asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46284828/tsql-excluding-the-rows-that-matches-with-temp-table) but I cannot use the "create temporary table" command in mySQL due to lack of permissions (I assume any other temporary table methods would also fail due to this reason...)

I have two tables:

**batch_table**

| BatchNo | Info |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | BBB |
| 101 | AAA |
| 102 | AAA |

---

**sample_table**

| SampleNo | SampleType | BatchNo | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Batch_QC_1 | 100 | 'pass' |
| 2 | Batch_QC_1 | 100 | 'pass' |
| 3 | Batch_QC_2 | 100 | 'pass' |
| 4 | Batch_QC_2 | 100 | 'pass' |
| 5 | Regular | 100 | 'positive' |
| 6 | Regular | 100 | 'positive' |
| 7 | Regular | 100 | 'negative' |
| 8 | Regular | 100 | 'negative' |
| 9 | Batch_QC_1 | 101 | 'pass' |
| 10 | Batch_QC_1 | 101 | 'QC_1 FAIL' |
| 11 | Batch_QC_2 | 101 | 'pass' |
| 12 | Batch_QC_2 | 101 | 'pass' |
| 13 | Regular | 101 | 'positive' |
| 14 | Regular | 101 | 'positive' |
| 15 | Regular | 101 | 'negative' |
| 16 | Regular | 101 | 'negative' |

---

I need to combine the batch_table and the sample_table, keeping only the "passing batches." Each batch is a key in the batch_table. I need to check the contents of the sample_table to see if a batch has passed. Passing is defined as ***all rows*** of the Status column = 'pass' where the SampleType is 'Batch_QC_1' or 'Batch_QC_2.' I then want to include/exclude by the entire BatchNo. So in the example data because there is a single row (sampleNo = 10) where the Status column is not 'pass' and where the SampleType column is 'Batch_QC_1'. I would like to exclude *all* of the rows with that same BatchNo ('101') instead of just that one.

I have tried many things - most seem to drop only the rows that do not equal 'pass' and do drop the all the rows with that same matching BatchNo.

For example I tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
sample_table.SampleNo, sample_tables.SampleType, sample_table.BatchNo, sample_table.Status, batch_table.Info

FROM 
batch_table
JOIN sample_table on batch_table.BatchNo = sample_table.BatchNo 
WHERE sample_table.Status NOT IN ('QC_1_FAIL', 'QC_2_FAIL')
```

This returns all rows except for row/sampleNo 10 from the sample_table where the Status = 'QC_2_FAIL'. What I would like is to exclude all of the rows with the same BatchNo as row 10 (or any row with the matching criteria).

***query result*** (single row excluded, SampleNo = 10)

| SampleNo | SampleType | BatchNo | Status | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Batch_QC_1 | 100 | 'pass' | BBB |
| 2 | Batch_QC_1 | 100 | 'pass' | BBB |
| 3 | Batch_QC_2 | 100 | 'pass' | BBB |
| 4 | Batch_QC_2 | 100 | 'pass' | BBB |
| 5 | Regular | 100 | 'positive' | BBB |
| 6 | Regular | 100 | 'positive' | BBB |
| 7 | Regular | 100 | 'negative' | BBB |
| 8 | Regular | 100 | 'negative' | BBB |
| 9 | Batch_QC_1 | 101 | 'pass' | AAA |
| 11 | Batch_QC_2 | 101 | 'pass' | AAA |
| 12 | Batch_QC_2 | 101 | 'pass' | AAA |
| 13 | Regular | 101 | 'positive' | AAA |
| 14 | Regular | 101 | 'positive' | AAA |
| 15 | Regular | 101 | 'negative' | AAA |
| 16 | Regular | 101 | 'negative' | AAA |

***desired result*** (all rows where BatchNo = 101 excluded)

| SampleNo | SampleType | BatchNo | Status | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Batch_QC_1 | 100 | 'pass' | BBB |
| 2 | Batch_QC_1 | 100 | 'pass' | BBB |
| 3 | Batch_QC_2 | 100 | 'pass' | BBB |
| 4 | Batch_QC_2 | 100 | 'pass' | BBB |
| 5 | Regular | 100 | 'positive' | BBB |
| 6 | Regular | 100 | 'positive' | BBB |
| 7 | Regular | 100 | 'negative' | BBB |
| 8 | Regular | 100 | 'negative' | BBB |

I tried using variations of left/right joins as well but I'm thinking that I the issue is more that I don't know how to structure the WHERE portion of the query properly. I think a temporary table might work but I can't seem to do this because of permissions. If not possible with a standard WHERE clause then is it possible to use a temporary variable of sorts to create an additional pass/fail column? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.SampleNo, s.SampleType, s.BatchNo, s.Status, b.Info FROM sample_table s 
INNER JOIN batch_table b on s.BatchNo = b.BatchNo
WHERE s.BatchNo NOT IN (
           SELECT DISTINCT(BatchNo) FROM sample_table WHERE Status != 'pass' AND 
           SampleType IN ('Batch_QC_2', 'Batch_QC_1')
          );
```

Comment: This looks close, but the criteria appears off from how I understand what the OP wants. The OP is wanting to exclude the batch #  of any samples that are not `pass` and are `Batch_QC_2` or `Batch_QC_1`. So the subquery criteria should be `WHERE Status != 'pass' AND SampleType IN ('Batch_QC_2', 'Batch_QC_1')` See: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kTLxyiPtuRTpDGWhze6R8B/0 as your query returns 0 results.

Comment: And besides, DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: @WillB. You're right, it must be `WHERE Status != 'pass' AND SampleType IN ('Batch_QC_2', 'Batch_QC_1')`

Comment: This solution solves my issue. I will read up on sub-queries! Thank you.